# Was it Allah's perfect plan when iblis reject to do Sajdah to Adam(A.S)?

Tags: allah, shaitan

As we believe, Allah has created each and every thing in this world, even one leaf of a tree can't move without the order of Allah Almighty. I often wondered was it Allah's perfect plan when iblis(satan) reject to do Sajda to Adam(A.S), as iblis(satan) is also a creature of Allah?

And in following ayat iblis explicitly showed his disobedience to God.Did the iblis have command to reject Allah's order?

And In Surah Al-Araf (12):

> [ Allah ] said, "What prevented you from prostrating when I commanded
>   you?" [Satan] said, "I am better than him. You created me from fire
>   and created him from clay."

I hope this is a valid question, if not then please feel free to edit and guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Well , this could lead to a wider discussion of determinism vs free will , but this is definitely out of scope of the question .
So here is my thoughts on this , remember when Allah said that he would create a new creation to inherit the earth and the angels voiced their concern ?

> وَإِذْ قَالَ رَبُّكَ لِلْمَلَائِكَةِ إِنِّي جَاعِلٌ فِي الْأَرْضِ خَلِيفَةً ۖ قَالُوا أَتَجْعَلُ فِيهَا مَن يُفْسِدُ فِيهَا وَيَسْفِكُ الدِّمَاءَ وَنَحْنُ نُسَبِّحُ بِحَمْدِكَ وَنُقَدِّسُ لَكَ ۖ قَالَ إِنِّي أَعْلَمُ مَا لَا تَعْلَمُونَ
>     And [mention, O Muhammad], when your Lord said to the angels, "Indeed, I will make upon the earth a successive authority." They said, "Will You place upon it one who causes corruption therein and sheds blood, while we declare Your praise and sanctify You?" Allah said, "Indeed, I know that which you do not know."
>   Quran 2:30

Notice how Allah said directly to the Angels that the new creation will inherit **The earth** , and that was before Adam was banished from heaven to Earth , in fact before Adam was created in the first place , so we know that without a shadow of a doubt Allah knew about this whole exchange between Satan and Adam , and that Satan would refuse to prostrate and all the events that would follow that and all the events before that actually , Allah knows everything all the time everywhere and anywhere .
**Now** This might tempt you to say that Satan shouldn't  be punished as he only follows what was ordered of him , here is where the fallacy lies .
Just because Allah knows what will happen doesn't mean he influenced anyone to choose the path they did , infact an analogy I read once about that says that having a time machine and traveling back and forth in time as a spectator isn't equivalent to having any influence on people's free will .
So Allah **knows** he would do that , he just didn't **Influence** Satan into doing it.
Thus preserving the freedom of will , which is guaranteed for both Human and Jinn(Satan) .

**To answer your question** : yes , Allah knew Iblis would do that , but he didn't command him to do it by any means , it was an internal drive from Iblis himself , his own arrogance and self-importance .